# OpenGL Multiplicative Blending mode

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to draw an image on top of a fully opaque background, using additive blending or multiplicative blending depending on a toggle.

Both work, but the alpha of the image gets ignored when doing multiplicative blending, while in additive it's working.

For additive I have:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE);
```

For multiplicative I have:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_DST_COLOR, GL_ZERO);
```

Additive works as expected, multiplicative ignores the alpha.

I am aware I can swap shaders to achieve what I want, but if I could do it through *glBlendFunc* it would be much better.

Comment: How should "multiplicative blending" incorporate the alpha?

Comment: Maximum alpha should behave like it does, minimum alpha should leave the background unchanged, in the middle it should interpolate. It's what most image editing software does. Is it possible through *glBlendFunc*?

Comment: "*in the middle it should interpolate*" Interpolate between what and what? You want linear interpolation between two values, but one of them is neither the source nor destination colors. Write down the math you actually want done, and then see if that fits into OpenGL's blending math.

Comment: final = dest.rgb * (1.0f - src.a) + (dest.rgb * src.rgb * src.a)
I think it's this. Does it make sense?

Comment: When I said interpolate between them, I meant the maximum and minimum alpha states, where `alpha = 0` meant the image doesn't get drawn at all, and `alpha = 1` is `dest.rgb * src.rgb`, which is what `glBlendFunc(GL_DST_COLOR, GL_ZERO);` yields.